# How to toggle visibilty of a Wizard Page of Devexpress XtraWizard control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a problem: I am using devexpress wizard control and want to toggle visibility of wizardpage on the basis of a checkbox input.

Problem:

If suppose checkbox A is checked then wizard page X must be visible while going to and fro in wizard control else page should not be visible.

What I have tried:

1. tried to toggle visibility in SelectedPageChanging event - didn't get success
2. tried to add or remove page from parent control - didn't get success

Please help me out in this..

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. handle the [`SelectedPageChanging` event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraWizardWizardControl_SelectedPageChangingtopic).
2. Check the [`Page` property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraWizardWizardPageChangingEventArgs_Pagetopic) of the event arguments is the page right before the page to show/hide.

   1. If true, set the [`Cancel` property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraWizardWizardPageChangingEventArgs_Canceltopic) to `true`.
   2. Set the [`SelectedPage`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraWizardWizardControl_SelectedPagetopic) to your desired page, depending on your checkbox A's state.

You could also optionally theck the [`Direction` property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraWizardWizardPageChangedEventArgs_Directiontopic) to see whether the user is navigating forward or backward.

**General hint:**

When dealing with DevExpress questions/issues, the [DevExpress Support Center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) always was the most useful location to ask my questions or browse for solutions.

Even Stack Overflow cannot compete with there speed and depths of anwsers (IMHO).

So if my answer (or the other answers) do not satisfy your need, I would recommend that you go to the Support Center and ask there for advise.

Comment: Thanks, but this will work only in case of I am moving formward and making e.Cancel=true will cancel the event itself

Answer (score 0):

I got this from devexpress below is the link for the same

[How to prevent a specific page from being activated](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1176)